# How to perform regulatory snapshots with the Interactive Brokers API?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am trying to access the TNA real time data via the Interactive Brokers API in Python. The connection and everything works fine, however I am getting back an error message that I do not understand.

Here is my code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
apple_contract = Contract()
apple_contract.symbol = 'TNA'
apple_contract.secType = 'STK'
apple_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
apple_contract.currency = 'USD'

#Request Market Data
res = app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, True, [])

time.sleep(10) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

In order to do the snapshot the second `"True"` in the app.reqMktData must be set.

When I execute the program, i get all ERROR -1 codes, which is okay, however the last error I do not understand:

> ERROR 1 10213 The API access is restricted to regulatory snapshot for
> TNA Stock (ARCA)

Did I do something wrong in the contract? Is this something regulatory like from the law? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/md_request.html#regulatory_snapshot  Do you have a subscription?  Just a guess as I don't use snapshots.

Comment: Thanks, but snapshots are especially used to avoid a subscription. Here you pay by demand